# Sanitise a high score table to remove offensive terms / usernames

Tags: leaderboards

I'm building an app for a client, which they've requested to have a publicly-visible high score table. It'll be displaying their username, which is a free-text field that the players can input. Player count is likely to be extremely low - I’d expect 10s or 100s/day at most.

The username field will be longer than 3 characters. The names will be tied to Firebase Auth accounts, but these are created through the app, not tied to anything like Google Play or a Facebook account or anything like that. I think they’re going to be fine with deleting obviously offensive names, but they’re not going to have massive resources devoted to manual moderation.

When I was a young lad, 100% of my local arcade cabinet high score tables consisted of a bunch of swear words and offensive terms (or variations of such words).

I can't imagine the internet has improved matters at all.

How can I sanitise usernames to make them safe for display?

Comment: Does the client wish to sanitize usernames? If not then it's really not your issue as of right now.

Comment: First thoughts: - Alert the client to this danger, ask if they want to spend money on your time to handle it. - Ask the client to give you a list of disallowed terms to scrub out. - Honestly, this is a minefield. Ask if they want it to be public at all.

Comment: See also: [the Scunthorp Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: Note that eg. Nintendo just do this manually.  There's simply no "AI available" to do this automatically.  Folks just immediately use foreign languages etc.  What you do is make a simple back-end page that makes it easy for the client to review them.

Comment: Not exactly the same thing, but similar enough: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)

Comment: Are emoticon allowed? How will the score board be  display? Can I ascii draw dong once I found  way to input the score in your scoreboard? May I enter Url  as name ("XYZ.com", "XYZ_Com", "XYZ_Dot_Com")?

Comment: @xdtTransform Or, carefully order your victories into an acrostic...

Comment: I've removed the discussion about the original image attached to this post; in this particular case, the image is not necessary to accurately describe the problem space. If anybody would like to continue that discussion or expand it to the more general topic of potentially-offensive images in posts, please post on [meta].

Comment: Are non-alphanumeric characters allowed? If so you're going to have a hard time flagging up Alan B'Stard.

Comment: @Josh: Thanks. Sorry for reviving it again.

Comment: @Josh I disagree. The image more accurately described the problem than the replacement text did: Off the top of your head, did *you* realize that DIK is offensive? It's a 3 letter combination that can be transformed into at least 2 offensive words, which is very relative to this question (how to regex for that?). As such, I've opened a question as you suggested: https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2814/where-is-the-line-between-informational-and-offensive

Comment: @Fattie If you have some sources and details to that claim? What is actually used in industry, by specific companies, sounds like the basis for a great answer!

Comment: Turns out this already had some great answers [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**I recommend you just let the client do it manually.**

From a cost perspective, you have luck on your side this time:

- You expect no more than 100 users/day, possibly as low as 10/day
- You have an authentication system, meaning bans can be permanent
- You have a client that is happy to delete names (infrequently)

The reality is, the 10 minutes it will take for somebody to look over the top leaderboards and ban any extreme names - will simply be cheaper and more reliable, than you spending time on an engineering solution (which will have problems).

With such a low playercount, it's unlikely this would need done often - even once per week during peak is likely to be enough.

---

**But I've got plenty of time, I can do something right?**

Wrong.

You can very easily do something wrong, that is more damaging to the client's brand than doing nothing at all.

Want to use Regex to catch all the bad names? Better hope you get it perfectly right, and also filter all false-positives from multiple databases of international real-people names:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

And even if you do manage the above successfully, players are not dumb - they will very easily find a way around your system to create an equally offensive name that you aren't catching.

At a minimum, you have just added even more work in keeping these rules updated, compared with the small manual work of just looking at the highest scores and banning.

---

**No but seriously, this is a kids game - the client has made it clear there can be NO TOLERANCE for offensive names. There has to be something!**

If this is honestly the case, and you cannot tolerate offensive names at all. The only realistic solution is just not to let your players create their own names.

This is the solution you'll find on almost all children's gaming websites, such as Cartoon Network.

Instead of giving a blank input, you give a selection of premade "name parts".
For example:

- An adjective, such as "Awesome", "Fantastic", "Cunning"
- A middle, such as "Bearded", "Laser-eye", "Pirate"
- A noun, such as "Master", "Winner", "Detector"

Which restricts display names to things like "Awesome Pirate Master".

*Do also give a quick consideration of what wordlists you are using. There is no point implementing this system if the user is able to fiddle names to get things that still sound offensive or dirty.*

Of course, there is the possibility for duplicates as well - but you can either write this off (3 lists of 100 words, already gives 1 million possible names) due to how few players you have, or if needed - you can still check that nobody else has the name on registration.

Realistically, this may be the most effective solution if you are seriously worried about bad names. But you do need to do a cost analysis, and find whether even making this system is really worth it compared to simple manual checks.

Comment: I like this answer, because "don't automate something until you know more about the problem" has almost always been the right thing to do in my experience.

Comment: I'll bite. What's wrong with "Big Fact Hunter"? Non-native English speaker here.

Comment: @Maurycy I'm a native speaker and I don't see the problem...

Comment: @Harabeck Maybe it's because of the initials? I mean I'm sure most initials combinations end up being offensive but this fits... https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/BFH

Comment: I'm editing that out, I'll be honest coming up with dirty names in a hurry isn't my strong point. It was just one that if you read fast, was meant to sound vaguely like something else. Sorry all >.<

Comment: Reminds me of Lego universe and penis detection.

Comment: The manual review option could always involve manually reviewing newly registered names and marking them as okay *before* they are permitted to appear in the high score table, instead of reviewing the high score table and removing the offensive names after they've already been published.

Comment: A 4 year old had gotten access to one of my console game where you can create characters.  That save slot was filled with poo, bum, pee, etc, etc.  Kids do this, and laugh, a lot...

Comment: [Do not underestimate the ability of kids to make rude sentences from supposedly-clean fragments](http://habitatchronicles.com/2007/03/the-untold-history-of-toontowns-speedchat-or-blockchattm-from-disney-finally-arrives/).

Comment: So, definitely don't include any animals (some are used as insults in their own right, others are anatomical slang), or foods (same reasons)

Comment: "But no, seriously, this is a kids game." Have you heard about Lego Universe? [Not even Lego could build a penis detector](https://www.exquisitetweets.com/tweets?eids=SOlZp2L8I8.SOl4CsO6YC.SOmhNAiuES.SOmlJ2T2Gq.SOmpjeGn1w.SOmwta15gX.SOmB4207kO.SOmJPgkOFU.SOmOl1j08a.SOmW0jPTRA.SOm72fKFfE.SOncwNl2SP.SOnlkgH05k.SOntnuAhGw.SOq). Name parts: "Cunning Linguist Pirate."

Comment: What stops the client from accidentally making a cultural faux pas? Even worse, now there is a person to blame rather than software

Comment: I remember my little nephew showing me some disney MMO where they used precisely this technique, it didn't stop the older kids from figuring out how to generate innuendo alas

Comment: The Dark Souls series has a similar speaking system and you could make dirty phrases like "try, but hole" and put it near characters bending over. I don't think a major goal was to completely eradicate all offensive language (the game is rated 17+), but it's just an example that even these systems can be abused.

Comment: @CaptainMan Or "Amazing chest ahead" in front of notable female characters.

Comment: I think renaming the user's display name should be enough. Leave 'xx_bigcock_15's record, maybe even let him log in like that, but do display him as 'FluffyBunny.' If you ban him, he will simply create a new account (with another offensive name), because you forced him to. Better give him incentive to keep the account.

Comment: For an example of an imperfect filter algorithm that generates false positives, look no further than Nintendo games.  Let's just say that if your game is intended to contain an entity named [Co**fag**rigus](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cofagrigus_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) [false positive emphasised], it would be good to either rename the entity, or code an exception into the sanitiser to prevent it from Scunthorping that entity.

Comment: @knallfrosch Then let him make another account. And then let him try to get another high score. Sounds like a solid incentive to keep him playing again and again, until he gets tired of making potty-name records, or god-forbid, grows up :)

Comment: @Mars You basically just said that yes, the banning approach will lead to a cat-and-mouse game, binding resources. I don't see any benefit to the game publisher.

Comment: @knallfrosch I agree there are better ways than simply banning - but I feel that they realistically come under the remit of the manual process, and outside the scope of this answer. It may be useful to have a separate question, about banning vs renaming vs shadowbanning (and any other technique), where they can be explored in depth.

Answer (score 7):

A small user-base is probably not enough to detract from the ease of implementing a blacklist. There are many libraries and/or word-lists such as [the ones referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532860/3838167) that can allow you to simply check usernames against whatever you deem inappropriate.

If you decided to attempt your own list, you probably want to use `regex` to filter out names.

As [Bilkokuya](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/175937/79588) points out, there may be issues with legitimate names getting blacklisted. *That is a business decision for your client to make*, but one that you can/should make them aware of. I am not aware of any ways to get around the cultural aspect, except that if you are expecting a large number of users from cultures where that may be an issue, you may want to implement region-specific filtering.

Reasons to implement some form of filtering (in addition to manual checks):

- Ease of implementation. Probably won't take more than an hour to get *something* going.
- A deterrent to the less-dedicated pranksters.
- Allows for checking at registration-time, lowering the chance that they will even reach the high score table.
- Works **with** manual checks.
- Seeing as it's an old problem, there should be many resources available.